# Check for null value for value types in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, key-value, value-type, reference-type

I have a `KeyValuePair(Of TKey,TValue)` and I want to check if it is null or not:

```
Dim dictionary = new Dictionary(Of Tkey,TValue)
Dim keyValuePair = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(Function(item) item.Key = *someValue*)

If keyValuePair isNot Nothing Then 'not valid because keyValuePair is a value type
    ....
End If

If keyValuePair <> Nothing Then 'not valid because operator <> does not defined for KeyValuePair(of TKey,TValue)
   ...
End If
```

How can I check if `keyValuePair` is null or not?

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is: "why are you using LINQ to find an entry in a Dictionary?"  You should be using the [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)` is a struct(Structure), it has default value which you can compare to.

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, string)
Dim keyValuePair = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(Function(item) item.Key = 2)

Dim defaultValue AS KeyValuePair(Of Integer, string) = Nothing

If keyValuePair.Equals(defaultValue) Then
    ' Not found
Else
    ' Found
End If
```

`Nothing` represents default value of the corresponding type.

But because you are searching `Dictionary` for a key, you can use `TryGetValue` instead

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, string)
Dim value As String

If dictionary.TryGetValue(2, value) Then
    ' Found
Else
    ' Not found
End If
```

Comment: I did check `keyValuePair.Equals(Nothing)`.

Comment: "Nothing represents default value for value types." This confuses me a bit. From the docs. "In Visual Basic, if you set a variable of a non-nullable value type to Nothing, the variable is set to the default value for its declared type. "